# Gulp with Angular 2 Environment variable

Tags: gulp, typescript, angular2

Добрый день, как можно передать параметр Angular-2 скрипту с помощью Gulp?
Чтобы в Angular-2 можно было получить значение этой переменной при запуске. Чтоб запуск gulp был примерно таким:

```
gulp start --type=dev
```

И чтоб в Ангуляр-2 можно было получить значение переменной `type`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно подключить модуль yargs

```
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
```

и делать со значениями все что захотите, например писать в файл:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("my_script.ts",
    "export class MyType {\n" +
    "    public gulpType: string = '" + argv.type + "';\n" +
    "}\n"
fsErr);
```

а файл уже импортировать куда надо...

Comment: да, спасибо, так и сделал, даже без yargs
просто через process env